# How to implement a try-catch block in scheme?

Tags: error-handling, scheme, try-catch, racket

I'm trying to implement a try-catch block in scheme using (call-cc) method but i'm not sure how it can be used for that. I could not find any example.

And found examples contains just error-handling but what i want to do is: if an error occurred, the scheme program has to give a message to user (via display for-example) without suspending the program.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you want to catch all errors, such as ones raised by both `raise` and `raise-continuable` you'd need both an exception handler (to deal with raised conditions) and an exit continuation (to avoid continuing with the `try` body).  Simple syntax for `try` would be:

```
(import (rnrs base)            ; define-syntax
        (rnrs exceptions))     ; get `with-exception-handler`

(define-syntax try
  (syntax-rules (catch)
    ((_ body (catch catcher))
     (call-with-current-continuation
      (lambda (exit)
        (with-exception-handler
         (lambda (condition)
           catcher
           (exit condition))
         (lambda () body)))))))
```

This gets used as, for example:

```
> (try (begin (display "one\n")
              (raise 'some-error)
              (display "two\n"))
    (catch (display "error\n")))
one
error
some-error       # the return value.
```

Note: this is R6RS (and R7RS) Scheme.

Comment: thank you for answer! that is what i was looking for but 'with-exception-handler could not be found. Also in racket and in r6rs.

Comment: Well, I ran the code in Ikarus...  `with-exceptions-handler` is found in the (rnrs exceptions) library.  See updated answer.  See section 7.1, page 24 or R6RS-Lib documentation.

Comment: Thanks!  Here (http://docs.racket-lang.org/r6rs/) is how you use (rnrs exceptions) in Racket.

Comment: Thank you! But well, and now the r6rs doesn't have the define-syntax but racket :) if you want, you can update your answer last time for correctness.

Answer (score 12):

Typically you'd use the `with-handlers` form. This lets you display an error message or take any other action before returning a value.

```
#lang racket

(define (foo x)
  (with-handlers ([exn:fail? (lambda (exn)
                               (displayln (exn-message exn))
                               #f)])
    (/ 1 x)))

(foo 1) 
; 1
(foo 0) 
; "/: division by zero" 
; #f
```

If you really want to use a continuation directly for some reason, you could use `call/ec` for an error/escape continuation instead of the general `call/cc`.

Docs:

- [with-handlers](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._with-handlers%29%29)
- [call/ec](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._call%2Fec%29%29)

Comment: try-catch is more clean qua comprehensibility But this way of exception handling seems more handy; and i'll use this i think :) thank you for the answer!

Comment: You can easily write a macro that uses `with-handlers` but looks more like try-catch: `(define-syntax try (syntax-rules (catch) [(_ e (catch [pred handle] ...)) (with-handlers ([pred handle] ...) e)]))`