# Scheme Lisp - Using eval for arbitrary arithmetic expressions

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, eval

I'm trying to evaluate arbitrary and nested arithmetic expressions in scheme with eval.
The expressions are build up from numbers, operators, constant bindings and parentheses.
For example, `(eval (+ 1 1))` or `(eval (+ (* 1 2) 3))`

The problem is, the expressions could also have unbalanced parentheses, like
`(eval ((+ 1 1))`, and the reader in scheme would just wait when the expression is entered
till all parentheses are closed and somehow matched.

I looked into quotation in scheme and by using a try-catch-mechanism in scheme
([How to implement a try-catch block in scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493079/how-to-implement-a-try-catch-block-in-scheme)) -
but that didn't work. I'm also thinking about implementing in scheme my own version of an evaluator for arithmetic expressions,
maybe with brackets as delimiters.

I search for a way to evaluate arbitrary expressions, and if the expression is
not valid, to get an error message like 'not valid expression' from eval, and not have the reader waiting for closing parentheses.

Edit:
See below for an implementation of a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as you say, the expressions you are trying to parse may have unbalanced parens, then those expressions clearly live in some unstructured data which is, almost certainly a sequence of characters of some kind.  Since the syntax of the expressions you want to read *is* a subset of the syntax of Scheme, then you can simply use the tool that the language provides for you: `read`: you definitely do not want to write your own parser for this unless you like spending a lot of time getting corner cases right.

Note that *any* parser which turns a sequence of characters into some object must at some point ask for the next character from the sequence.  There are two things that can happen in response to that:

- it can get a character, possibly after waiting for something on the other end of that sequence – a human perhaps – to generate the character;
- it can get an indication that there are no more characters – an end-of-file indicator of some kind.

No magic you can do can avoid that.  So the problem you describe of the reader waiting for the close-paren is not real: *any parser you write* will have the same problem, when reading from an interactive stream: it simply has to wait for the human on the other end of that stream to either type something, or to indicate that the stream is complete, at which point it can decide whether what it saw was well-formed or not.

So the answer to the turning-sequences-of-characters-into-object part of your problem is to use the `read` provided by the language.  Here is one approach to doing that – since you have specified that you are using Racket, this uses Racket, rather than RnRS Scheme for any n.  Almost all of this code would not be needed if you did not care about restricting the reader somewhat (and I am not sure I have restricted it enough).  The rest of it deals with handling exceptions from the reader, and turning them into multiple values.

```
(define (read-thing source)
  ;; Read some object from a source port.
  ;; Return two values: either the object read and #t,
  ;; or some exception object and #f if something went wrong.
  ;;
  ;; This tries to defang the reader but I am not sure it does enough
  (with-handlers ([exn? (λ (e) (values e #f))])
    (call-with-default-reading-parameterization
     (thunk
      (parameterize ([read-accept-lang #f]
                     [read-accept-reader #f])
        (values (read source) #t))))))

(define (read-thing-from-file f)
  ;; read a thing from a file
  (call-with-input-file f read-thing))

(define (read-thing-from-string s)
  ;; read a thing from a string
  (call-with-input-string s read-thing))
```

So now we can try this:

```
> (read-thing-from-string "foo")
'foo
#t
> (read-thing-from-string "(foo")
(exn:fail:read:eof
 "read: expected a `)` to close `(`"
 #<continuation-mark-set>
 (list (srcloc 'string #f #f 1 1)))
#f
```

As you can see the second value tells you whether `read` raised an exception or not.

Now you can use this thing-reader to feed an evaluator.  For instance you can use a function like this:

```
(define (read-and-evaluate reader source
                           evaluator environment)
  ;; Read something with a read-thing compatible reader from source
  ;; and hand it to evaluator with environment as a second argument
  ;; If read-thing indicates an error then simply raise it again.
  (call-with-values
   (thunk (reader source))
   (λ (thing good)
     (when (not good)
       (raise thing))
     (evaluator thing environment))))
```

So now, the problem is reduced to writing `evaluator`, which I'm not going to do.

Here is an example of this function being used with a trivial evaluator which simply returns the form it has been given.

```
> (read-and-evaluate
   read-thing-from-string "(foo)"
   (λ (form env) form) #f)
'(foo)
> (read-and-evaluate
   read-thing-from-string "(foo"
   (λ (form env) form) #f)
; string::1: read: expected a `)` to close `(` [,bt for context]
```

Of course, the whole handling-the-exception-in-the-reader thing is not needed here, since all I end up doing it reraising it, but it does show you how you can handle such an error.

---

A note on writing an evaluator.  It is tempting to say that, well, `(+ 1 2)` is a valid Scheme expression, and Scheme has `eval` so just use that.  This is like using a thermonuclear device to demolish a house: it does a good job of demolishing the house but it has undesirable consequences such as killing hundreds of thousands of people.  Consider, for instance, that `(system "rm -rf $HOME")` is *also* a valid Racket expression, but one you may not want to run.

To avoid this kind of code-injection attack you want to restrict the evaluator as much as you possibly can, so it will evaluate *only* the language you are interested in.  The same applies to the reader: above the full Racket reader can, I am almost sure, evaluate arbitrary Racket code at read-time: I've tried (but probably failed) to defang it above.

Racket has a significant set of tools which let you define a more restricted language, for which `eval` would be safe.  However for a *really* simple language such as evaluating arithmetic expressions it is almost certainly simpler to simply write your own evaluator.  It certainly is more educational to do so.

Comment: Thank you, awesome :-) I was going to use Chez Scheme, but I will switch to Racket now. I will use this and study it. :-) - also regarding restrictions. An extra evaluator shouldn't be necessary, or? Because then I have valid lisp code and can just eval it.

Comment: @gm123: I've written an appendix on why just using `eval` is generally not a good idea.

Comment: haha yeah 'thermonuclear device' got the message across ...got it - I will try to implement eval myself, should be doable

Comment: Got a solution now below working by using your procedure definitions, thank you. Any suggestions? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your strategy will not work. Scheme has "try-catch", but just like "try-catch" in most programming languages, it only works on runtime error (the error that occurs as your program runs). The unbalanced parentheses problem, in contrast, is a syntax error (the error the occurs when reading your program).

For example, in Python, you can write:

```
try:
  1 / 0
except:
  pass
```

which would catch the error, but it would not catch a syntax error like:

```
try:
  if
except:
  pass
```

If you want to allow the input to have unbalanced parentheses, then you need the input as a string instead of as an expression in the language itself. For example:

```
(define my-input "(+ 1 1")
```

is perfectly fine, but:

```
(define my-input (+ 1 1)
```

is not.

It is annoying, however, to compute on an input string. Therefore, the next step that you should do is to tokenize and parse the input string into a tree. This is also where you can detect the unbalanced parentheses and report an error:

```
(define (parse input-string)
  ;; TODO
  )

(parse "(+ 1 2)")
;; expect '(+ 1 2)
(parse "(+ 1 2")
;; expect an error: "not valid expression"
```

Suppose that `parse` doesn't error, then you would have a tree like `'(+ 1 2)` as an output. The next step is to write a function that consumes a tree and produces an answer

```
(define (interp input-tree)
  ;; TODO
  )

(interp '(+ 1 2))
;; expect 3
(interp '(+ (+ 5 6) 7))
;; expect 18
```

Your `eval` is then simply a composition of `parse` and `interp`:

```
(define (eval input-string)
  (interp (parse input-string)))

(eval "(+ 1 2)")
;; expect 3
(eval "(+ 1 2")
;; expect an error: "not valid expression"
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! It makes now sense for me regarding syntax errors. So much for "lisps have now syntax". I will implement it now with a tokenizer/parser.

Comment: @gm123: that's a bad idea.  Just use `read` and catch errors from it.

Comment: Yes, using `read` is another option -- to reuse the parser that Scheme implements already.

Comment: @tfb Thank you both - I started to look into parsers, which is also nice. Also thanks again for the clarification regarding exceptions an syntax errors. Yes, I was hoping for some 'secret lisp weapon', because with a custom-parser is it how it would be done in other languages I guess and would mean more work and maybe be not as much powerful as with 'read'. Nice, I'm eager now to try it. Thank you.

Comment: I see now, that the writing of an custom `eval` is necessary, because otherwise it would be to dangerous in general. Got a solution now below.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @tfb and @sorawee-porncharoenwase I got a working solution now.
which in my opinion is save regarding the execution of arbitray Scheme/Racket expressions,
some of which could be unhelpful.

Let's play first with the procedure definitons of @tfb.

`(+ 1 b)` is a valid Scheme/Racket expression, so `read-thing-from-string` should declare it as valid.

```
(let-values ([(expr is-valid-expr) (read-thing-from-string "(+ 1 b)")])
    (if is-valid-expr "Valid Scheme/Racket expression" "Not valid Scheme/Racket expression"))

;; -> "Valid Scheme/Racket expression"
```

`(( 1 b)` isn't a valid Scheme/Racket expression, as `read-thing-from-string` recognizes.

```
(let-values ([(expr is-valid-expr) (read-thing-from-string "(( 1 b)")])
    (if is-valid-expr "Valid Scheme/Racket expression" "Not valid Scheme/Racket expression"))

; -> "Not valid Scheme/Racket expression"
```

I just want to be able to evaluate arbitrary arithmetic expressions,
like `(+ 1 1)`, but nevertheless a expression like `(a b 1)` is a valid Scheme/Racket expression and should be recognized as such.

```
(let-values ([(expr is-valid-expr) (read-thing-from-string "(a b 1)")])
    (if is-valid-expr "Valid Scheme/Racket expression" "Not valid Scheme/Racket expression"))

;; -> "Valid Scheme/Racket expression"
```

Now that we can recognize valid Scheme/Racket expression, we can evaluate them with our own
evaluation procedure. We could have used Scheme's/Racket's `eval`, but that would be in general
dangerous.
For the writing of a custom evaluation procedure, I took heavy inspirations from the book
"Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs", Chapter "Metalinguistic Abstraction".

In the book there's much more going on regarding the setup an manipulation of the environment,
because the evaluation procedure there is for interpreting Scheme code -- I just want to be able
to interpret arithmetic expression, and thereby can keep the handling of the environment more
simple.

```
(define envr (hash 'a 1 'b 2 '+ + '- - '* * '/ /)) 

(define (eval-expr expr envr)
  (cond ((self-evaluating? expr) expr)
        ((variable? expr) (lookup-variable-value expr envr))
        ((application? expr)
         (apply-proc (eval-expr (operator expr) envr)
                             (list-of-values (operands expr) envr)))
    (else (error "Not valid arithmetic expression: EVAL-EXPR" expr))))


(define (self-evaluating? expr)
  (if (number? expr) true false))

(define (variable? expr)
  (symbol? expr))

(define (lookup-variable-value var envr)
  (with-handlers ([exn:fail? (lambda (exn)
                               (error "Unbound identifier: LOOKUP-VARIABLE-VALUE" var))])
    (hash-ref envr var)))


;; Page 505: "A procedure application is any compound expression that is not
;; one of the above expression types. The car of the expression is
;; the operator, and the cdr is the list of operands:"
(define (application? expr) (pair? expr))
(define (operator expr) (car expr))
(define (operands expr) (cdr expr))
(define (no-operands? ops) (null? ops))
(define (first-operand ops) (car ops))
(define (rest-operands ops) (cdr ops))


(define (apply-proc procedure arguments)
  (if (primitive-procedure? procedure)
      (apply procedure arguments)
      (error "Unknown procedure type: APPLY-PROC" procedure)))


(define (list-of-values exps envr)
  (if (no-operands? exps)
      '()
      (cons (eval-expr (first-operand exps) envr)
            (list-of-values (rest-operands exps) envr))))


(define primitive-procedures
   (list (list '+ +)
         (list '- -)
         (list '* *)
         (list '/ /)))


(define primitive-procedure-objects
  (map (lambda (proc) (cadr proc))
        primitive-procedures))


(define (primitive-procedure? proc)
  (member proc primitive-procedure-objects))
```

We got now everything to evaluate expressions:

```
;; Example evaluations ;;

(with-handlers ([exn:fail? (lambda (exn)
                           (exn-message exn))])
    (eval-expr 1 envr))

; -> 1


(with-handlers ([exn:fail? (lambda (exn)
                           (exn-message exn))])
    (eval-expr 'b envr))

; -> 2


(with-handlers ([exn:fail? (lambda (exn)
                           (exn-message exn))])
    (eval-expr '(+ 1 b) envr))

; -> 3


(with-handlers ([exn:fail? (lambda (exn)
                           (exn-message exn))])
    (eval-expr '(> 1 b) envr))

; -> "Unbound identifier: LOOKUP-VARIABLE-VALUE >"



(let-values ([(expr is-valid-expr) (read-thing-from-string "(+ 1 b)")])
    (if is-valid-expr (eval-expr expr envr) "Not valid Scheme/Racket expression"))

; -> 3

(let-values ([(expr is-valid-expr) (read-thing-from-string "(( 1 b)")])
    (if is-valid-expr (eval-expr expr envr) "Not valid Scheme/Racket expression"))

; -> "Not valid Scheme/Racket expression"
```